# Windows 10, symbolic link: difference in behavior, bash vs cmd shell

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-10, symlink

I have a single bash script that I use to launch many programs.
I called this script `launcher.sh`
To use it, I create a symbolic link named `myprog` pointing to `launcher.sh`.

While in bash shell (MSYS2/MINGW64)
inside `launcher.sh`, I determine the name of the "script itself" ($0 or $BASH_SOURCE) and I get "myprog" and, so, I can proceed accordingly.

While in CMD shell
inside `launcher.sh`, I determine the name of the "script itself" and I get "launcher" and, so, I don't know what program I am supposed to launch.

Is there a solution to this problem?

---

**Charles:**

Thanks for your question. I went ahead a tested the scenario you described and when `bash` is started from within `cmd`, it does work as expected.

Below, please find a sample session; observe the following sequence:
1.- directory listing of where the symlink is
2.- the content of `launcher.sh`
3.- failed execution of `myprog.sh` from `cmd.exe`
4.- starting bash from `cmd.exe`
5.- successful execution of `myprog.sh` from within `bash`

```
1.- 
C:\Users\salazag>dir C:\Programs\spgcodes\myprog\0.5.0\win10\bin
 Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
 Volume Serial Number is 1C58-10A0

 Directory of C:\Programs\spgcodes\myprog\0.5.0\win10\bin

09/12/2020  01:34 PM    <DIR>          .
09/12/2020  01:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/08/2020  08:19 PM    <SYMLINK>      info [C:\Programs\spgcodes\launchinfo.sh]
09/11/2020  03:26 PM    <SYMLINK>      myprog.sh [C:\Users\salazag\Desktop\launcher.sh]
09/08/2020  08:20 PM           630,612 myprog.x
               3 File(s)        630,612 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  244,660,219,904 bytes free

2.- 
C:\Users\salazag>type .\Desktop\launcher.sh
#!C:/Programs/msys64/usr/bin/bash
this=$BASH_SOURCE
echo "this script name=$this"

3.- 
C:\Users\salazag>myprog.sh
this script name=C:\Users\salazag\Desktop\launcher.sh

4.- 
C:\Users\salazag>bash
salazag@md2ysbtc /c/Users/salazag> myprog.sh     # <--5
this script name=/c/Programs/spgcodes/myprog/0.5.0/win10/bin/myprog.sh

salazag@md2ysbtc /c/Users/salazag>
```

---

**Mofi:**

Yes, I am well aware that `bash` and `cmd` are two different interpreters. Not sure if you noticed, but I am not asking `cmd` to interpret a `bash` script; all I am asking is for Windows/cmd to handle a symbolic link that way it is supposed to.

Symlinks have existed for a while in Unix before they were ever implemented on Windows; and, per [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links#:%7E:text=A%20symbolic%20link%20is%20a,in%20exactly%20the%20same%20manner.) itself:

> Symbolic links are designed to aid in migration and application
> compatibility with UNIX operating systems. **Microsoft has implemented
> its symbolic links to function just like UNIX links**.

And, so, all I am asking is whether I am missing something for as long as Microsoft claims that symlink are supposed to behave the same way in Windows as they do in Unix...including the result from "$0".

Comment: Just to be clear: When you have the problem, it's a copy of bash _started by `cmd`_ that's having the problem, right? (As opposed to having built a polyglot script, and having it sometimes interpreted by bash and sometimes interpreted by cmd).

Comment: ...if so, I might retitle this to something like: *Can a copy of bash started by cmd.exe get the name of the symlink cmd followed to find the bash script?* -- wordier, to be sure, but also specific about what the question to be answered is.

Comment: Well, well, well...I just noticed that PowerShell does handle the symbolic link correctly.